# How to smoothly animate current position with a custom LocationSource in Google Maps SDK?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am using a custom `LocationSource` that provides updates every 300+ ms.

Below you can observe that the coordinates updates are making the blue dot (current position) move in quite a shaky way (I was moving slow to make the effect more obvious):

[image: Current not so smooth movement]

How can I make the blue dot's movement smoother, similar to the one in the Google Maps application? Less left-right shakes and smoother forward movement instead of "jumping" from point A to point B would be awesome.

There are some answers that recommend animating the camera or using an interpolator to animate movement between 2 known positions over a preset timeframe but that doesn't really apply to my situation.

Comment: Just add some [animations](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko could you please say what kind of animation are you more precisely recommending?

Comment: Do you think there could be a way to animate the "MyLocation" blue dot while using a custom `LocationSource`? Or I will actually need to show my own kind of location marker?

Comment: "show my own" - yes. You should store some location points in buffer (and probably smooth path) and use custom "MyLocation" marker with animation.

Comment: I'm trying out the `ValueAnimator`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use SnapToRoad Api to get correct co-ordinates from one location to other location.  



 public void animateMarker(int startPositionId, final LatLng toPosition, Marker marker, final boolean hideMarke) {

        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = routeMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 1000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;


                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);

                Log.d("run:t", String.valueOf(t));

                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;


                Log.d("run:lat", String.valueOf(lat));
                Log.d("run:lng", String.valueOf(lng));
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
             

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                   

                    handlerSetPosition.postDelayed(this, 8);


                } else {
                    if (hideMarke) {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                        pointId = startPositionId + 1;
                        getSnappedRout(pointId);


                    }
                }
            }
        };
        handlerSetPosition.post(runnable);

    
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it would've been useful to mention this detail: my app does indoor positioning using Bluetooth beacons, so I am quite constrained in using Maps APIs unfortunately...